# No intrinsics for x86 BMI instructions BLSI & BLSR in Clang?

Tags: assembly, x86, clang, bit-manipulation, bmi

I wanted to try out some intrinsics for [the x86 BMI set](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#cats=Bit%20Manipulation). The `grep bmi /proc/cpuinfo` shows both `bmi1` and `bmi2` in my AMD Ryzen CPU. But I cannot get clang to compile some of the instructions, in particular [BLSI](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blsi) & [BLSR](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blsr). It looks like they are not supported in [clang's `bmiintrin.h`](https://web.archive.org/web/20230207174142/https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/bmiintrin_8h_source.html). Is that indeed so or do I miss something? In general, do you need to install some kind of "plugin" for LLVM from Intel/AMD or something like that to use CPU-specific features? Is it better to use their build tools in this case?

Following [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20231105192053/https://tearth.dev/posts/performance-of-bit-manipulation-instructions-bmi/), I build a test program with BLSI or BLSR unstructions:

```
// test_bmi.c
#include <x86intrin.h>
// not #include <bmiintrin.h> - clang errors and asks for x86intrin.h
volatile unsigned long long result;

main() {
  ...
  for (unsigned long long i=0; i<max_count; i++) {
    result = _blsi_u64(i);
  }
}
```

It's built with `-march=native` to turn on all of the CPU features:

```
clang -march=native test_bmi.c -o test_bmi
```

But there are no `blsi`-like instructions in `objdump -d test_bmi` assembly. Looking at [the bliintrin.h source](https://web.archive.org/web/20230207174142/https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/bmiintrin_8h_source.html), it seems the BLSI and BLSR instructions are not actually supported:

```
static __inline__ unsigned long long __DEFAULT_FN_ATTRS
__blsi_u64(unsigned long long __X)
{
  return __X & -__X;
}
```

But, for example, BEXTR is in the header and it does show up in the `objdump` assembly:

```
static __inline__ unsigned long long __DEFAULT_FN_ATTRS
__bextr_u64(unsigned long long __X, unsigned long long __Y)
{
  return __builtin_ia32_bextr_u64(__X, __Y);
}

$ objdump -d test_bmi | grep bextr
    12c5:  c4 e2 f0 f7 c0         bextr  %rcx,%rax,%rax
```

Does it mean that clang does not really support the BLSI & BLSR instructions? Is that on purpose or did I miss something to enable them?

Comment: fuz's answer is right in general.  This is a missed-optimization bug you should report on https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/

Answer (score 3):

No special intrinsics are needed as clang knows to use these instructions and others like it (including `andn`, `bextr`, `popcnt` (!), `blsi`, `blsmsk`, `blsr`, and `tzcnt` (!) and others) if you just code out their behaviour in C.

For example, you can write

```
int my_blsi(int x)
{
    return (x & -x);
}
```

and find that the compiler turns this into something like

```
my_blsi:
    blsil   %edi, %eax
    ret
```

This peephole analysis is pretty powerful and can even recognise common implementations of `popcnt` (both with a loop and with bit manipulation), `tzcnt`, and similar instructions.

So just write code like you normally would and compile for a target architecture that supports the instructions you are looking for.  The compiler will use them where appropriate automatically.

Note that you may need to compile with optimisations for these optimisations to trigger; this could explain your initial failure to get `blsi` generated.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/zeE86G1z5 shows the OP is right, Clang 17 *did* screw this up and fail to use `blsi` in this loop.  This missed optimization happens with older Clang, too; none of the versions I tried on Godbolt used `blsi`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Fascinating!  Looks like a missed optimisation to me.

Comment: Perhaps the `i++` loop-counter increments are throwing it off, like trying to take advantage of that somehow results in IR that no longer matches the BLSI peephole?  It's not actually using `neg` or `sub`; oh, it's counting one counter up, one counter down! (and `and`ing them)  /sigh.